# How to make the following code wait for and api call to be ready before resuming?

Tags: javascript

The following code loops through a `formFields` array. There are two types of fields: those with files to upload and those that don't. I'm keeping count of the "queued" fields and the "finished" ones, so I know when to update the form

```
const payload = {}
const fields = {
  queued: [],
  finished: []
}

formFields.forEach(field => {
  fields.queued.push(field)
  if (hasUploadFiles(field)) { // FOR FILE INPUTS
    utils.mapCallPromise(field.value, file => {
      api.uploadPhoto(file, field).then(uploadedPhoto => {
        payload[field.name] = uploadedPhoto
        fields.finished.push(field)
      })
    })
  } else {  // FOR NORMAL INPUTS
    payload[field.name] = field.value
    fields.finished.push(field)
  }
})

if (fields.queued.length === fields.finished.length) {
  console.log('use the payload to update the form')
}
```

The problem is `api.uploadPhoto` is triggering *after* `if (fields.queued.length === fields.finished.length)`.

How to modify the code so `if (fields.queued.length === fields.finished.length)` triggers after `api.uploadPhoto` is done?

**UPDATE:**

This is `api.uploadPhoto` and `utils.mapCallPromise`:

```
api.uploadPhoto = async (file = {}, field = {}) => {
  if (utils.includes(api.usServers, api.env)) {
    return await usImageUpload.toFirebase(file, field)
  } else {
    return await cnImageUpload.toQCloud(file, field.userId, field.sizes)
  }
}

utils.mapCallPromise = (object, callback) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(object).map(value => {
      return resolve(callback(value))
    })
  })
},
```

Comment: asynchronous code is tricky - you'll need to use `Promise.all`

Comment: @JaromandaX I know ... that's why I'm asking this question ha.

Comment: @JaromandaX Could you please give me a sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Promise.all and array map method, you could do the following

```
Promise.all(formFields.map(field => {
    if (hasUploadFiles(field)) { // FOR FILE INPUTS
        return api.uploadPhoto(file, field).then(uploadedPhoto => {
            return {field, uploadedPhoto};
        });
    } else {  // FOR NORMAL INPUTS
        return {field};
    }
})).then(results => {
    //results is an array of objects that are either {field, uploadedPhoto} or just {field} 
});
```

Comment: Do I need to add `fields.queued.length === fields.finished.length` Somewhere? `results` is triggering before the result of `api.uploadPhoto`.

Comment: odd, unless `api.uploadPhoto` "resolves" too early - in that case, the `api.uploadPhoto` code is wrong - is that your code? or some library

Comment: Please see **UPDATE** in my question.

Comment: do `usImageUpload.toFirebase` and `cnImageUpload.toQCloud` return **promises** that are only resolved when appropriate?

Comment: This is the `usImageUpload.toFirebase` function: https://gist.github.com/alexcheninfo/83dbd78aa2c985a398008350cde0f56b

Comment: then I'll have the same question about `mountainImagesRef.put` - seriously, can you just determine it yourself